# Is there a jQuery UI "anti-sortable" that will let LI's be taken and from a UL, but always specifying order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, design-patterns

I have something partially working where there are two UL's, both having had jQuery UI `.sortable()` called on it. The user can and potentially should drop LI's from one to the other. I am looking to have the second list really be sortable, but the first list retain a single ordering instead of having a LI from the second list appended at the end if the user clicks on it.

I see one painfully obvious way to do it: keep a JavaScript list of values of LI's, or alternately set a `data-index='0'` (then, 1, 2, 3, etc.), and then in either case make a single, possibly bottom-up, sweep of the dread bubble sort.

This appears to me something I could straightforwardly get working, but it has an "**If you're doing it this way, you're working too low-level**" code smell to me. Apart from a bubble sort reference, in a case where I think O(n) really is tolerable, it seems like something where someone who knew jQuery UI could produce a much shorter and clearer implementation.

I've outlined above the hard way of addressing my problem. What easy ways should I consider instead.

Comment: So you want to drag some one list of static data to another list that can be sortable?

Comment: Yes, to and back (or more simply move items with one click). The second UL, initially empty, has what items the user clicks or drags over from the first UL. This should remove the item from the first UL. However, if the user reconsiders and moves an item back from the second UL to the first UL, I'd like the newly moved element to return to its original place among those items in the first UL that are still (or again) present in the first UL.

Comment: Maybe you want draggable and not sortable with droppable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more hesitation, I decided to go with the obvious solution, even if it doesn't smell like a usual jQuery optimal solution. I added an ascending integer `data-` field to the original LI's in the server-side code that generates them, and client-side created a single bubble sort iteration function that should work if all but the last item (re-added items start out last) are in order:

```
var get_index = function(node)
    {
    return parseInt(jQuery(node).attr('data-sort-position'));
    };
var sort_available = function()
    {
    var len = jQuery('#available > li').length;
    if (len >= 2)
        {
        var moved = false;
        for(var index = 0; index < len; index += 1)
            {
            if (!moved)
                {
                if (get_index(jQuery('#available > li')[index]) >
                  get_index(jQuery('#available > li')[len - 1]))
                    {
                    var node = jQuery(
                      jQuery('#available > li')[len - 1]).detach();
                    jQuery(node).insertBefore(
                      jQuery('#available > li')[index]);
                    moved = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I then added a `sort_available()` call to the end of the handler that is called when a member of the other, destination list is clicked:

```
    jQuery('#included li').click(function(event)
        {
        jQuery(event.target).detach();
        jQuery('#available').append(event.target);
        assign_clicks();
        sort_available();
        });
```

Now it seems to be putting items back in their original places.